# Weblogic + Docker + Vagrant = Connection Issue

Tags: vagrant, docker, weblogic-10.x, vagrantfile, dockerfile

first time poster, but have been very impressed with this community.  I've spent an embarrassing amount of time this week trying to resolve this issue - there doesn't seem to be much info on the net & I am stuck.  Thanks in advance for any insights!

I am moving an existing WLS application into Docker.  Goal is to have a repeatable Dev environment with WLS inside container & those containers running inside Vagrant (custom RHEL 6.5 VirtualBox).

I configured & started WLS container.  I am also able to access WLS services from the container on VM.  However, when I try to access the container from the host, I receive a connection timeout error.

I am running a private network 10.10.10.41 on Vagrant with port forwarding 7771:7001 - if I access that IP:Port (as I normally would when running a service within Vagrant), I get a connection refused.

I am able to run WLS "natively" from the VM and access from the host successfully.  I am also able to run Apache conatiners from within the VM and access them from the host successfully.  So the issue appears specific to WLS running inside a container in VM.

I turned off the firewall on the VM, which I've read is a common issue with Vagrant + Docker.

I have a whole host of information to share, but rather than drink from the firehose I will start out with a couple pieces.  Happy to attach any further info as necessary.  Thanks again!

Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.10.10.41"

config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 7771, guest: 7001
```

Dockerfile
  EXPOSE 7001

Dockerrun

```
docker run -d -p 7001:7001 -v /my/release:/domain/release --name "wladmin" --link wlmanaged:wlmanaged my/wladmin
```

Container IP

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' wladmin
172.17.0.13
```

nmap VM (localhost)

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000044s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
25/tcp  open  smtp
111/tcp open  rpcbind
```

nmap VM (Vagrant private network IP)

```
Nmap scan report for 10.10.10.41
Host is up (0.000053s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
111/tcp open  rpcbind
```

nmap WLS Docker Container

```
Nmap scan report for my.domain.com (172.17.0.11)
Host is up (0.000055s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
7001/tcp open  afs3-callback
7002/tcp open  afs3-prserver
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the root cause & wanted to share back.

It turns out that because Vagrant has a private network adapter, we have to bind the container to that adapter using.

```
docker run -d -p 10.10.10.41:7001:7001 -v /my/release:/domain/release --name "wladmin" --link wlmanaged:wlmanaged my/wladmin
```